# Create this instance

Tags: php, instance

i have hundred of class model (Model of MVC system).
How i can create instance with relational class?

example in class there is method like this:

```
class object {
    /**
     * Simply create new instance of this object
     * @return object
     */
    function createNewInstance() {
        $class_name = __CLASS__;
        $return = new $class_name;
        return $return;
    }
}
```

As we can see, i use `__CLASS__` to get relational name if this class.
Is there any better way to create instance?
i heard there is reflection method to do it?

Comment: what wrong with __construct() ?

Comment: @eicto this has nothing to do with construct. What i want is, to have method that create new of that object and return that. But didn't want to hardcoding class name, since i have hundred of different class name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems you need get_class()
http://codepad.org/yu6R1PDA

```
<?php
class MyParent {
    /**
     * Simply create new instance of this object
     * @return object
     */
    function createNewInstance() {
        //__CLASS__ here is MyParent!
        $class_name = get_class($this);
        return new $class_name();
    }
}

class MyChild extends MyParent {
   function Hello() {
    return "Hello";
    }
}

$c=new MyChild();
$d=$c->createNewInstance();
echo $d->Hello();
```

[this](http://codepad.org/UZken7ag) also works:

```
class MyParent {
    /**
     * Initialise object, set random number to be sure that new object is new
     */
    function __construct() {
    $this->rand=rand();
    }

}

class MyChild extends MyParent {

   function Hello() {
    return "Hello ".$this->rand;
    }
}

$c=new MyChild();
$d=new $c;
echo $c->Hello()."\n";
echo $d->Hello()."\n";
```